# How to use slim templates with backbone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, slim-lang

How to use slim templates with backbone?

I use in my ruby-on-rails application backbone-on-rails gem that uses eco templates. But in my  project I user slim templates engine and of course I want to use just one template type. But how I can switch to slim in backbone?

Gem backbone-rails from codebrew offers erb and haml, so I think I can use slim too. But how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fat-free client-side templates with Slim and CoffeeScript:  https://github.com/jfirebaugh/skim

Comment: I am currently using this with Backbone

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confusing the difference between client-side templating and server-side templating.  Slim, HAML end ERB are Ruby server-side templating libraries.

Eco is a node.js server-side templating library.  Templates can be compiled into client-side templates with Eco, but it is dependent on node.js to compile the templates on the server.

It's important to understand that when you create a server-side template, the rendered result generally ends up in your browser as HTML, the template itself never ends up in the browser.  With client-side templating, the template itself exists on the browser and the template is rendered via JavaScript (in this case, backbone.js) to produce the HTML on page.